# How do I obtain the dependency fcitx-dbus?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, lightdm, fcitx

When I run `fcitx`, I get the following errors.

```
$ (INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-dbus.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-autoeng.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-ipc.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-lua.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-freedesktop-notify.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-remote-module.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-spell.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-kimpanel-ui.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-fullwidth-char.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-notificationitem.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkb.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-keyboard.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xim.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-punc.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-clipboard.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-vk.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-chttrans.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-imselector.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-unicode.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-x11.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-classic-ui.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkbdbus.conf
(INFO-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-quickphrase.conf
(WARN-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:298) Disable addon fcitx-ipc, dependency fcitx-dbus can not be satisfied.
(WARN-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:298) Disable addon fcitx-freedesktop-notify, dependency fcitx-dbus can not be satisfied.
(WARN-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:298) Disable addon fcitx-kimpanel-ui, dependency fcitx-dbus can not be satisfied.
(WARN-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:298) Disable addon fcitx-notificationitem, dependency fcitx-dbus can not be satisfied.
(WARN-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:298) Disable addon fcitx-xkbdbus, dependency fcitx-xkb,fcitx-dbus can not be satisfied.
(ERROR-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/frontend/xim/xim.c:240) Start XIM error. Another XIM daemon named none is running?
(ERROR-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/instance.c:427) Exiting.
(ERROR-3262 /build/buildd/fcitx-4.2.8.3/src/lib/fcitx/frontend.c:556) No available frontend
```

There does not exist a package in my apt-get repository called `fcitx-dbus`, but there is one called `fcitx-module-dbus`, which I attempted to install and was notified was already installed.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

What are some suggested next steps to debug this issue?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? 4 years later & it still seems to be broken...

Answer (score 1):

According to [packages_ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/fcitx-module-dbus/download) you need to add `trusty main universe` repo to the `sources.list` :

**Example** :

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe
sudo apt-get update
```

First , you need to fix broken package:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then reinstall `fcitx` using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install fcitx-module-dbus
```

Comment: When I install it, it just says it's already installed.

Comment: try to remove it `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove fcitx-data`

Comment: Tried that already and re-installed. Same effect.